# Contact form in flash: AS3 checking if php sent the email *problem*

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, contact-form

Contact form in flash with AS3 to PHP.

My problem is that the function "showdata" in AS3 does not take variables from the PHP code. It can't see the **data=success** from PHP, so i always get "error" even though the email was successfully sent.
Can you help me by suggesting what to change in function "showdata" or anything else functional?

*I am testing on a online server*

PHP code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $subject =$_POST[theme];
        $message=$_POST[msg];
        $mail_from=$_POST[email];
        $header="from: $name <$mail_from>";
        $to ='test@test.gr';
        $sending=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);       
        if ($sending) 
            {
            echo "answer=success";
            }   
        else
            {
            echo "answer=error";
            }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

AS3 code

```
sendbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,trysend);
function trysend(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if (subject.text == "") {
        statustext.text = "give theme";
    } else if (isValidEmail(from.text) != true) {
        statustext.text = "give email.";
    } else if (body.text == "") {
        statustext.text = "write a message";
    } else {
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.theme = subject.text;
        variables.email = from.text;
        variables.msg = body.text;

        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "mail.php" );
        urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        urlRequest.data = variables;

        var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
        loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showData);
        loader.load(urlRequest);
    }
}

function showData(evt:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader=URLLoader(evt.target);
    var resulting:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader.data);
    if (resulting.answer == "error") {      
        statustext.text = "Success!";
    } else if (resulting.answer == "success"){
        statustext.text = "error...";
        subject.text="";
        from.text="";
        body.text="";
    }
}


//Validation Email
function isValidEmail(email:String):Boolean {
    var emailExpression:RegExp = /^[a-z][\w.-]+@\w[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]*[a-z][a-z]$/i;
    return emailExpression.test(email);
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `trace(loader.data);`?

Comment: Isn't the problem on the PHP side? Try doing this `if ($sending) { echo "data=success"; } else { echo "data=error"; } ` and then, on the _showData_ function change/add the condition `if (result.data == "error") { ... }`.

Comment: @ bmleite : still not functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it works now like this:**

**PHP** (dont put it in 'html' 'head' 'body' tags. Create a file only with this code: )

```
<?php
    $subject =$_POST[theme];
    $message=$_POST[msg];
    $mail_from=$_POST[email];
    $header="from: $name <$mail_from>";
    $to ='test@test.gr';
    $sending=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    if ($sending){      
    print 'response=success';}
?>
```

**ActionScript3**:

```
    function trysend(e:MouseEvent):void{
    Theme = subject.text;
    Email = from.text;
    Message = body.text;

    if (Theme == "") {
        statustext.text = "give a theme";
    } else if (Email == "") != true) {
        statustext.text = "give an email.";
    } else if (Message == "") {
        statustext.text = "give a message";
    } else {

        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.theme = Theme;
        variables.email = Email;
        variables.msg = Message;

        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mail.php");
        urlRequest.method  = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        urlRequest.data = variables;

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.load(urlRequest);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showData);
    }
}


    function showData(evt:Event):void {
        var Result:URLVariables = new URLVariables(evt.target.data);
        if (Result.response == "success") {
            statustext.text = "Success!";
            subject.text="";
            from.text="";
            body.text="";
        } else {
            statustext.text = "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The best practice is to put your URLLoaders *outside* your function. This way it will not be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

`loader.data` must contain the string echoed by your PHP code. You have to put it in a `URLVariables` in order to have it parsed.

```
function showData(evt:Event):void {
    var result:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader.data);
    if (result.data == "success") {
    ...
```

And by the way, set your loader as a member variable and don't write function inside functions ;)

Comment: Dear Friend. Thanks for responing. Must i change only the lines you wrote down? or also something else? i still don't get a result. How about your suggestions uppon function inside function? Can you write down the whole code as you think it could work for me? Thanks in advance

Comment: could you tell me if your `trace (loader.data)` returns something?

Comment: No it doesn't return something. The way the code is, the if always leads to else

Comment: Ok, put the declaration `var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();` at the topmost of your code (outside any function). And put all the `showData` function outside (after) the `trysend` function. Anyway I'm a bit concerned by the fact your trace doesn't print anything...

Comment: You confirm that putting a `trace (loader.data)` at the beginning of `showData`won't print anything? Is your PHP file UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: trace (loader.data) prints the whole php if i test it in Flash editor. PHP is now utf-8 encoded, but still no effect. I gtg now. Thanks for help. if you find something please post it and i will get it later.

Comment: The whole php? You can't test php locally on your file system. You have to use a local server (easyPHP, WAMP) or a remote one to test that. To get the trace online, you need to install a debug version of the Flash player and Flashtracer for FF.